# ComboBox with Suggested mode & hierarchical view

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Currently developing accounting system but I need to show accounts like below :

[image]

Or like this
[image]

Any solution ?

Comment: No solution but a suggestion: Google `.net custom multicolumn autocomplete /  combobox`

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to do this

[image]

in the misc you have to do this

[image]

Hopefully this helped